# TSQL how to do sub calculations

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I have SQL results like the first results in the pic below , but I would like to modify it to sum the price by customer as seen in the second part in the pic. payment id and price are in one table, customer is in a second table.

This is SQL for first results:

```
select 
    p.payment_id, p.price, c.customer 
from 
    payments p 
left join 
    customers c on p.payment_id = c.payment_id
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM (p.price) price, c.customer 
  FROM payments p LEFT JOIN customers c on p.payment_id = c.payment_id
GROUP BY c.customer
```

Comment: This grouping did group by customer, but it did not result in the sum I need. It still listed all payment ids instead of reducing it down to two records with summed up price.

Comment: Ended up needing to do another sub query and the summed worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(p.price) as price, c.customer 
from payments p 
left join customers c 
on p.payment_id = c.payment_id
group by c.customer 
order by c.customer
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `GROUP BY` clause & `SUM()` aggregate function

```
select  SUM(p.price) AS price, c.customer 
from payments p 
left join customers c 
  on p.payment_id = c.payment_id
group by c.customer
```